# chat implementation using JS postmeassge call and Iframe in HTML code

Tags: iframe, postmessage, livechat

After page loads, on click of a link in the, the SRC of Iframe is updated and event listener is called, so that the server call is made to retrive the Auth code for particular session and Cookie.

By fetching the auto code Chat is being triggered to agent and current user, but when we close the chat window and re-initiate the chat clicking the same link mentioned above is not working in IE where it works in all other browser

Issue is in IE the Event listener method is not called while re-initiating the chat,(There i no console error)

```
document.getElementById('messaging-frame').src = "https://xxx.xycucb.com/dfs/auth/oauth/v2/authorize?response_type=code&scope=openid%20LivePerson_USER_INFO&client_id=l7xx1b05ca43b3e44f76870af803f33d6d75&redirect_uri=https://www.xycucb.com/liveperson/oauth&state=openidconnect_test_state";
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (4*1000));
    expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = "ENVC=oauthlogin-vst0;" + expires + ";path=/;domain=.xycucb.com";
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
    var locationURL = '';
    // Listen to message from child window
    eventer(messageEvent,function(event) {
        var key = event.message ? "message" : "data";
        if(key === "data"){
            locationURL = event.data.location;

        }else{
            locationURL = key.location;

        }
if (locationURL && !isAuthCodeReceived) {
                  isAuthCodeReceived = true;
                console.log("locationURL is present" );
            var oauthCode = (locationURL.split("=")[1]).split("&")[0];
            console.log("oauthCode is " + oauthCode);
           var result = {
                ssoKey: oauthCode,
                redirect_uri: "https://www.xycucb.com/liveperson/oauth"
            };
            callback(result)
        }
    }, !1)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Questions that are well-written and structured are more likely to get answered. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info. Specifically, I'd suggest proofreading to avoid spelling & grammar issues, formatting your title like a question, and letting people know what you've tried already to fix the issue.

Comment: Initially it was not working in IE, later by changing the Internet setting in IE it started working intermittently.

The setting changes was,
Setting icon -- > Internet Option -- > Advanced tab.
Scroll to bottom to security section and Unchecked the "Warn about certificate address missmatch"